# Deployment on windows 7 64 bit os while trying to installing Windows application 2010 with crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2007

I am getting deployment problem while installing Windows application developed using VS2010, access 2007 and Crystal Reports on windows 7 32 bit

First i got the following error.

The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine while data export to MS ACCESS.I installed MS access database engine 2007 and Target Platform of my application to **x86** ( which was initially set to **AnyCPU**)

MS access provider problem got resolved by installing Access database engine and changing the target platform to x86

Then i clicked a button to see reports.I got error "could not load assembly "crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine".

I resolved it by installing Crystal Report Runtime 64 bit for .NET framework 4.0.

Now i am getting "The type initializer for crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an exception "

I found some forums suggest that if u set Platform -> ANY CPU, it would get resolved.
But when i set platform - any cpu, i am getting msaccess problem again.

Please help me to find the solution for deploying Windows Application with Crystal Reports (developed vs2010 and msaccess 2007,windows 7 os 32 bit) on Windows 7 64 bit msaccess 2007.

Please provide a right solution to get rid of all deployment issue.It works finely on my system.

Development Setup:
Windows 7 32 bit
VS2010
Access 2007

Deployment Setup:
MS access 2007
window 7 64 bit

My windows application should run without any msaccess or report issue.

Thanks
Padma

Answer (score 1):

While deploying application developed on 32 bit machine on 64 bit machine.Do the following

1.Build all projects under solution to X86 Platform.

2.Then in production machine,install all the necessary components for 32 bit.

Note Please do not install 64 bit components then it works finely for me.

I uninstalled all the components in my production server, next i installed my application.
Then i started installing components on receiving error messages while running my application.

Finally i got rid of all errors and it works finely for me.